# Using nest-csv-parser to parse CSV into objects

Tags: typescript, csv, csv-parser

I have a structure of `class`es in Typescript that are nested.

```js
export class Vehicle {
  id: string;
  brand: string;
  owner: Owner;
}
export class Owner {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

I then have a CSV file from which I intend to load this structure.

```
id;brand;owner.id;owner.name
1;mazda;100;James
...
```

I'm having an issue with these nested values, since the `id` and `brand` are loaded correctly but the owner is not recognized by `nest-csv-parser`.

The parsing:

```js
const stream = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file.csv');
const entities = await this.csvParser.parse(stream, Vehicle, undefined, undefined, { separator: ';'});
```

Please note that nest provides a `CsvParser` module that is actually being imported.

Is there a way to successfully import this nested structure?

Thanks in advance.